# Why do I need an additional capture group in my Regex to be able to match the pattern

Tags: .net, regex, regex-group

I have the following regex im using in .NET:

```
^(?(?=\d+\S*|\S*\d+)([\d\S]*))\s?(.*)$
```

It has two capture groups and it should match the following strings:

```
1a Teststreet
```

Capture group 1: 1a
Capture group 2: Teststreet

```
Teststreet
```

Capture group 1:
Capture group 2: Teststreet

When I try to match this the described way, with the first example it only matches the Teststreet part and leaves group 1 empty (should be 1a)

To let it work correctly in .NET I need to add a third capture group around the housenumber group like this:

```
^(?(?=\d+\S*|\S*\d+)(([\d\S]*)))\s?(.*)$
```

My question is: why?
On https://regex101.com it works without the extra capture group (which will always be empty)

Comment: It is due to the difference in how conditional construct works in PCRE and .NET. It has been asked already, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38991092/net-regex-with-condition-lookbehind-and-capture-group). Also, note that `[\d\S]` = `\S`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Couldnt find the other (duplicate) issue you mentioned.